# Is there any way to automate the logging of the generated native queries in Torque?

Tags: logging, orm, apache-torque

Is there anything similar to the "show_sql" config property of Hibernate in Torque which allows for logging of the generated queries?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to add P6Spy for printing SQL](http://wiki.apache.org/db-torque/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_to_add_P6Spy_for_printing_SQL) or simply change your logging level to `DEBUG`